# c#, oledb connection string issue

Tags: c#, connection-string, oledb

I'm using .net4.0 and c# language.
In my code i have a connection string

```
oleConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                   Data Source = " + filepath + ";
           Extended Propertie s= \"Excel 12.0;HDR=yes\"";
```

and it work well. But when i change a connection string like this:

```
oleConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                   Data Source =" + filepath + "; 
           Extended Properties =\"Excel 12.0;HDR=no\"";
```

(I change HDR parameter for "no")
I got error: No value given for one or more required parameters.
error from `"Microsoft Office Access Database Engine".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your referencing a column using say [A1] then this will fail.  With HDR=No the columns are referenced as F1, F2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

OleDb Connection HDR Default is YES ans there is no option for that.

Check:

[Connection strings for Access 2007](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007)

Regards

Comment: How does that answer the op question?

Answer (score -1):

There is no `HDR=no`....

The default behavioour is no headers. So just leave out the HDR part completely - that will also mean no headers.

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500.aspx

Comment: where can i find parameters list?