# Select Statement for Excel Datasource

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am connected to Excel sheet, which is acting as database. I need to select some records with where condition but I am getting error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

by using below code:

```
Dim conn As Object
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
XLName = "C:\Users\X\Desktop\rawdata.xlsx"
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & 
XLName   & "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';"
conn.Open connString
rs.Open ("SELECT * FROM [data$] where industry='Government'"), conn, 
adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close  
conn.Close
```

Comment: Are you sure the "below code" is **exactly** what you have in the Visual Basic Editor? Because that code can't compile without the `_` line continuations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set HDR=NO the column titles from the excel table will be ignored and it will be used internal names. See older answer: [c#, oledb connection string issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684416/c-oledb-connection-string-issue)